# How do you get the stream associated with a thrust execution policy?

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to be able to get the stream-id which is associated with an execution policy in thrust. I am trying to access [this function](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/1.8.0/thrust/system/cuda/detail/execute_on_stream.h#L74).

I have tried this :

```
cudaStream_t stream = 0;
auto policy = thrust::cuda::par.on(stream);
cudaStream_t str = stream(policy);
```

but I am getting a compilation error :

```
stream.cu(7): error: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
```

Could I get some ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

"I am trying to access this function." Trying to directly use e.g. things in `detail` are part of the implementation and may change from one version to the next.  To wit: the file you are referring to does not even exist in the the current thrust distributed with CUDA 10.

However, this seems to work for me:

```
$ cat t354.cu
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(){
  cudaStream_t mystream;
  cudaStreamCreate(&mystream);
  auto policy = thrust::cuda::par.on(mystream);
  cudaStream_t str = stream(policy);
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cudaStream_t); i++)
    if (  *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&mystream)+i) != *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&str)+i)) {std::cout << "mismatch" << std::endl; return -1;}
  std::cout << "match" << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o t354 t354.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t354
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
match
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```